# AngularJS populate select trough ng-options with simple Map

Tags: angularjs, json, dictionary, ng-options, angularjs-select

I didn't find anything that can help me on this trouble.
I need to populate a select in an angular project. The problem is simple, all the other selects that I populated I had a json data like this

```
[{"id":1, "value":"A"},{"id":1, "value":"B"},{"id":1, "value":"B"}]
```

now instead my json data is a simple TreeMap structure like this

```
{1: "Jun 2011", 2: "Jul 2011", 3: "Aug 2011", 4: "Sep 2011"}
```

So, this isn't an array but an object and I wouldn't change the be service but I don't know if is possibile to populate a select with this type of object.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="..." ng-model="data.selected" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in options">
    <option value="">Select date</option>
</select>
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcfLn4xg/)**